# Complicated (for me) reshaping from wide to long in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, reshape

Individuals (indexed from 0 to 5) choose between two locations: A and B.
My data has a wide format containing characteristics that vary by individual (ind_var) and characteristics that vary only by location (location_var).

For example, I have:

```
In [281]:

df_reshape_test = pd.DataFrame( {'location' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 'dist_to_A' : [0, 0, 0, 50, 50, 50], 'dist_to_B' : [50, 50, 50, 0, 0, 0], 'location_var': [10, 10, 10, 14, 14, 14], 'ind_var': [3, 8, 10, 1, 3, 4]})

df_reshape_test

Out[281]:
    dist_to_A   dist_to_B   ind_var location location_var
0    0            50             3   A       10
1    0            50             8   A       10
2    0            50            10   A       10
3    50           0              1   B       14
4    50           0              3   B       14
5    50           0              4   B       14
```

The variable 'location' is the one chosen by the individual.
dist_to_A  is the distance to location A from the location chosen by the individual (same thing with dist_to_B)

I'd like my data to have this form:

```
    choice  dist_S  ind_var location    location_var
0    1        0       3         A           10
0    0       50       3         B           14
1    1        0       8         A           10
1    0       50       8         B           14
2    1        0      10         A           10
2    0       50      10         B           14
3    0       50       1         A           10
3    1        0       1         B           14
4    0       50       3         A           10
4    1        0       3         B           14
5    0       50       4         A           10
5    1        0       4         B           14
```

where choice == 1 indicates individual has chosen that location and dist_S is the distance from the location chosen.

I read about the [.stack](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) method but couldn't figure out how to apply it for this case.
Thanks for your time!

NOTE: this is just a simple example. The datasets I'm looking have varying numbers of location and number of individuals per location, so I'm looking for a flexible solution if possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, pandas has a `wide_to_long` command that can conveniently do what you intend to do.

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'location' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 
                'dist_to_A' : [0, 0, 0, 50, 50, 50], 
                'dist_to_B' : [50, 50, 50, 0, 0, 0], 
                'location_var': [10, 10, 10, 14, 14, 14], 
                'ind_var': [3, 8, 10, 1, 3, 4]})

df['ind'] = df.index

#The `location` and `location_var` corresponds to the choices, 
#record them as dictionaries and drop them 
#(Just realized you had a cleaner way, copied from yous). 

ind_to_loc = dict(df['location'])
loc_dict = dict(df.groupby('location').agg(lambda x : int(np.mean(x)))['location_var'])
df.drop(['location_var', 'location'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
# now reshape
df_long = pd.wide_to_long(df, ['dist_to_'], i = 'ind', j = 'location') 

# use the dictionaries to get variables `choice` and `location_var` back.

df_long['choice'] = df_long.index.map(lambda x: ind_to_loc[x[0]])
df_long['location_var'] = df_long.index.map(lambda x : loc_dict[x[1]])
print df_long.sort()
```

This gives you the table you asked for:

```
              ind_var  dist_to_ choice  location_var
ind location                                        
0   A               3         0      A            10
    B               3        50      A            14
1   A               8         0      A            10
    B               8        50      A            14
2   A              10         0      A            10
    B              10        50      A            14
3   A               1        50      B            10
    B               1         0      B            14
4   A               3        50      B            10
    B               3         0      B            14
5   A               4        50      B            10
    B               4         0      B            14
```

Of course you can generate a choice variable that takes `0` and `1` if that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks Zhen Sun, this looks like a much cleaner approach.
However, it's doesn't match what my problem was. The `location` variable doesn't have a mistake. The `dist_to_`variable should have the distance between the individual (given by the index) and the location. The choice indicates what the individual chose at this opportunity (did she choose location A or B). I tried to make this clear in my question, but if it's still not clear let me know and I can rewrite it a bit.

Comment: @cd98, I think I understand your question. I am saying in your long table, the `location` variable does not look quite right. How can `ID = 0` has `location` both `A` and `B`? `ID = 0` is located at `A` based on your wide table. Moreover, I don't quite get why the approach does not match your problem.

Comment: ID identifies the individual. Each individual chooses between choice A or B. The original data has only data for the choice the individual takes. The "long" format I was looking for has both choices per individual and the characteristics of the choice, including characteristics that depend on just the individual (ind_var), just the location (location var) or on both the individual and the choice (such as location). Each ind. choose just one location. It's a weird format, but it's what my stats program required. Sorry if it wasn't clear, hope it is now! Thanks for your helpfulness!

Comment: @cd98, now I understood! The data are indeed stored in a very weird way. I thought the `location` var is the location of the individual. In fact it is the location of choice, and apparently, the individual locations are not in the data. Nonetheless, please see the edited code. I made a dictionary to create a correspondence between the individuals and the `location` variables before reshape.

Comment: nice work. I've accepted your answer, since it's much cleaner than mine.

Comment: Might not be relevant for this particular case but in my case `pd.melt()` was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit curious why you'd like it in the format.  There's probably a much better way to store your data.  But here goes.

```
In [137]: import numpy as np

In [138]: import pandas as pd

In [139]: df_reshape_test = pd.DataFrame( {'location' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B
', 'B'], 'dist_to_A' : [0, 0, 0, 50, 50, 50], 'dist_to_B' : [50, 50, 50, 0, 0, 
0], 'location_var': [10, 10, 10, 14, 14, 14], 'ind_var': [3, 8, 10, 1, 3, 4]})

In [140]: print(df_reshape_test)
   dist_to_A  dist_to_B  ind_var location  location_var
0          0         50        3        A            10
1          0         50        8        A            10
2          0         50       10        A            10
3         50          0        1        B            14
4         50          0        3        B            14
5         50          0        4        B            14

In [141]: # Get the new axis separately:

In [142]: idx = pd.Index(df_reshape_test.index.tolist() * 2)

In [143]: df2 = df_reshape_test[['ind_var', 'location', 'location_var']].reindex(idx)

In [144]: print(df2)
   ind_var location  location_var
0        3        A            10
1        8        A            10
2       10        A            10
3        1        B            14
4        3        B            14
5        4        B            14
0        3        A            10
1        8        A            10
2       10        A            10
3        1        B            14
4        3        B            14
5        4        B            14

In [145]: # Swap the location for the second half

In [146]: # replace any 6 with len(df) / 2 + 1 if you have more rows.d 

In [147]: df2['choice'] = [1] * 6 + [0] * 6  # may need to play with this.

In [148]: df2.iloc[6:].location.replace({'A': 'B', 'B': 'A'}, inplace=True)

In [149]: df2 = df2.sort()

In [150]: df2['dist_S'] = np.abs((df2.choice - 1) * 50)

In [151]: print(df2)
   ind_var location  location_var  choice  dist_S
0        3        A            10       1       0
0        3        B            10       0      50
1        8        A            10       1       0
1        8        B            10       0      50
2       10        A            10       1       0
2       10        B            10       0      50
3        1        B            14       1       0
3        1        A            14       0      50
4        3        B            14       1       0
4        3        A            14       0      50
5        4        B            14       1       0
5        4        A            14       0      50
```

It's not going to generalize well, but there are probably alternative (better) ways to get around the uglier parts like generating the choice col.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I agree it's a weird format, I only need it because Stata's [asclogit](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?asclogit) command for conditional logit (i.e alternative varying characteristics) demands a dataset with this shape.
I'll try your solution today and maybe some other posters will chime in.

Comment: Fair enough.  Have you had a look at [statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/)?  It's a python package for econometrics/statistical inference.  I'm not sure that anyone has implemented conditional logit, but it's got all the basics covered.

Comment: I looked at [statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/), but so far they only have Multinomial Logit (individual varying characteristics). However, it seems they are working on Conditional Logit right now (see [this blog](http://gsocstatsmodels.blogspot.com/) )

Comment: I tried to implement TomAugspurger code to my real dataset (which has around 60 different choice locations, not just A and B and a different number of individuals per location chosen) and I haven't figured out how to make it work in my case.
I'm looking at multi-indexing over individuals and choices to see if that is the way.

Comment: Hmm, sorry to hear it didn't work.  Let me know if anything else comes up.  BTW the `pd.get_dummies()` function may come in handy for you with that many locations.

Comment: Hi, thanks again. The `get_dummies()`looks like something I'll have to use later.
I've posted a simplified version of this question in case you want to have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730252/reindexing-and-filling-nan-values-in-pandas)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this took longer that I expected, but here's a more general answer that works with an arbitrary number of choices per individual. I'm sure there are simpler ways, so it would be great if somebody can chime in with something better for some of the following code.

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'location' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 'dist_to_A' : [0, 0, 0, 50, 50, 50], 'dist_to_B' : [50, 50, 50, 0, 0, 0], 'location_var': [10, 10, 10, 14, 14, 14], 'ind_var': [3, 8, 10, 1, 3, 4]})
```

which gives

```
    dist_to_A   dist_to_B   ind_var location   location_var
0    0           50          3     A            10
1    0           50          8     A            10
2    0           50         10     A            10
3    50          0           1     B            14
4    50          0           3     B            14
5    50          0           4     B            14
```

Then we do:

```
df.index.names = ['ind']

# Add choice var

df['choice'] = 1

# Create dictionaries we'll use later

ind_to_loc = dict(df['location'])
# gives ind_to_loc equal to {0 : 'A', 1 : 'A', 2 : 'A', 3 : 'B', 4 : 'B', 5: 'B'}

ind_dict = dict(df['ind_var'])
#gives  { 0: 3, 1 : 8, 2 : 10, 3: 1, 4 : 3, 5: 4}

loc_dict = dict(  df.groupby('location').agg(lambda x : int(np.mean(x)) )['location_var']  )
# gives  {'A' : 10, 'B' : 14}
```

Now I create a Multi-Index and do a re-index to get a long shape

```
df = df.set_index( [df.index, df['location']] )

df.index.names = ['ind', 'location']

# re-index to long shape

loc_list = ['A', 'B']
ind_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
new_shape = [  (ind, loc) for ind in ind_list for loc in loc_list]
idx = pd.Index(new_shape)
df_long = df.reindex(idx, method = None)
df_long.index.names = ['ind', 'loc']
```

The long shape looks like this:

```
         dist_to_A  dist_to_B  ind_var location  location_var  choice
ind loc                                                              
0   A            0         50        3        A            10       1
    B          NaN        NaN      NaN      NaN           NaN     NaN
1   A            0         50        8        A            10       1
    B          NaN        NaN      NaN      NaN           NaN     NaN
2   A            0         50       10        A            10       1
    B          NaN        NaN      NaN      NaN           NaN     NaN
3   A          NaN        NaN      NaN      NaN           NaN     NaN
    B           50          0        1        B            14       1
4   A          NaN        NaN      NaN      NaN           NaN     NaN
    B           50          0        3        B            14       1
5   A          NaN        NaN      NaN      NaN           NaN     NaN
    B           50          0        4        B            14       1
```

So now fill the NaN values with the dictionaries:

```
df_long['ind_var'] = df_long.index.map(lambda x : ind_dict[x[0]] )
df_long['location']  = df_long.index.map(lambda x : ind_to_loc[x[0]] )
df_long['location_var'] = df_long.index.map(lambda x : loc_dict[x[1]] )

# Fill in choice
df_long['choice'] = df_long['choice'].fillna(0)
```

Finally, all that is left is creating dist_S
I'll cheat here and assume I can create a nested dictionary like this one

```
nested_loc = {'A' : {'A' : 0, 'B' : 50}, 'B' : {'A' : 50, 'B' : 0}}
```

(This reads: if you're in location A, then location A is at 0 km and location B at 50 km)

```
def nested_f(x):    
    return nested_loc[x[0]][x[1]]

df_long = df_long.reset_index()
df_long['dist_S'] = df_long[['loc', 'location']].apply(nested_f, axis=1)

df_long = df_long.drop(['dist_to_A', 'dist_to_B', 'location'], axis = 1 )

df_long
```

gives the desired result

```
    ind loc ind_var location_var    choice  dist_S
0    0   A   3         10            1      0
1    0   B   3         14            0      50
2    1   A   8         10            1      0
3    1   B   8         14            0      50
4    2   A   10        10            1      0
5    2   B   10        14            0      50
6    3   A   1         10            0      50
7    3   B   1         14            1      0
8    4   A   3         10            0      50
9    4   B   3         14            1      0
10   5   A   4         10            0      50
11   5   B   4         14            1      0
```