# Reindexing and filling NaN values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, reshape

Consider this dataset:

```
data_dict = {'ind' : [1, 2, 3, 4], 'location' : [301, 301, 302, 303], 'ind_var' : [4, 8, 10, 15], 'loc_var' : [1, 1, 7, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

df_indexed = df.set_index(['ind', 'location'])
df_indexed
```

which looks like

```
           ind_var loc_var
ind location        
1   301      4      1
2   301      8      1
3   302     10      7
4   303     15      3
```

ind_var is a variable that varies by ind ( = individual) and loc_var varies by location.
(I also have an extra variable that varies by both ind and location, but I'm omitting it to simplify the presentation)

I need to transform the data to have each individual index contain all the possible locations.
I can reindex in this way (just showing individuals 1 to 3):

```
new_shape = [(1, 301), (1, 302), (1, 303), (2, 301), (2, 302), (2, 303), (3, 301), (3, 302), (3, 303)]
idx = pd.Index(new_shape)
df2 = df_indexed.reindex(idx, method = None)
df2.index.names = ['id', 'location']
```

which gives

```
        ind_var loc_var
id  location        
1   301     4     1
    302    NaN   NaN
    303    NaN   NaN
2   301     8     1
    302    NaN   NaN
    303    NaN   NaN
3   301    NaN   NaN
    302    10     7
    303    NaN   NaN
```

but I need a way to fill the missing values, so that I get:

```
        ind_var loc_var
id  location        
1   301     4     1
    302     4     7
    303     4     3
2   301     8     1
    302     8     7
    303     8     3
3   301    10     1
    302    10     7
    303    10     3
```

I tried two different things with no success:

1) Using a loc_dict = {301 : 1, 302 : 7, 303 : 3} to replace loc_var and a ind_dict = {1 : 4, 2: 8, 3: 10, 4 : 15} to replace ind_var

2) Using a groupby method.

```
# First reset index
df_non_indexed = df2.reset_index() 
df_non_indexed['loc_var'] = df_non_indexed.groupby(['location'])['loc_var'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(method='ffill'))
```

This almost works, but only does the fill forward (or backwards)

There must be a very simple way of doing this, but I haven't been able to figure it out!
Thanks for your time.

*Note*: this is related to my question [reshaping from wide to long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688155/complicated-for-me-reshaping-from-wide-to-long-in-pandas). I've taken a different approach and simplified in hope that this one is easier to understand.

Comment: I think you're second table has a typo.  The values for (2, 201) should be moved to (2, 202)

Comment: What is the desired output (not a fill forward?)

Comment: My first instinct would be to have a list of dictionaries `[{'301':(4,1), '302':(nan, nan), '303':(nan,nan)}, {'301':...}` and so on. If you worked with this dictionary, filling it in, might it then be easier to extract the data_dict that you want? Sorry unfamiliar with pandas

Comment: @TomAugspurger: I don't think there's a typo, I made the example so that both indiv 1 and 2 choose the same location, 301

Comment: AndyHayden: I've added the table with the way the data should look like. The 'ffill' method fills in only some of the NaN, but not the ones that are "behind" the non-missing value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by `stack/unstack` and `groupby` very easily:

```
# unstack to wide, fillna as 0s
df_wide = df_indexed.unstack().fillna(0)
# stack back to long
df_long = df_wide.stack()
# change 0s to max using groupby.
df_long['ind_var'] = df_long['ind_var'].groupby(level = 0).transform(lambda x: x.max())
df_long['loc_var'] = df_long['loc_var'].groupby(level = 1).transform(lambda x: x.max())
print df_long
```

This gives you the results:

```
                   ind_var  loc_var
ind location                  
1   301             4        1
    302             4        7
    303             4        3
2   301             8        1
    302             8        7
    303             8        3
3   301            10        1
    302            10        7
    303            10        3
4   301            15        1
    302            15        7
    303            15        3
```

Answer (score 2):

Much cleaner solution than my original.  Thanks @cd98

```
In [41]: loc_dict = {301 : 1, 302 : 7, 303 : 3}

In [42]: ind_dict = {1 : 4, 2: 8, 3: 10}

In [198]: df2 = df2.reset_index()

In [199]: df2
Out[199]: 
   index  id  location  ind_var  loc_var
0      0   1       301        4        1
1      1   1       302      NaN      NaN
2      2   1       303      NaN      NaN
3      3   2       301        8        1
4      4   2       302      NaN      NaN
5      5   2       303      NaN      NaN
6      6   3       301      NaN      NaN
7      7   3       302       10        7
8      8   3       303      NaN      NaN

In [200]: df2['ind_var'] = df2.id.map(ind_dict)

In [201]: df2['loc_var'] = df2.location.map(loc_dict)

In [202]: df2
Out[202]: 
   index  id  location  ind_var  loc_var
0      0   1       301        4        1
1      1   1       302        4        7
2      2   1       303        4        3
3      3   2       301        8        1
4      4   2       302        8        7
5      5   2       303        8        3
6      6   3       301       10        1
7      7   3       302       10        7
8      8   3       303       10        3

In [203]: df2 = df2.set_index(['id', 'location'])

In [204]: df2
Out[204]: 
             index  ind_var  loc_var
id location                         
1  301           0        4        1
   302           1        4        7
   303           2        4        3
2  301           3        8        1
   302           4        8        7
   303           5        8        3
3  301           6       10        1
   302           7       10        7
   303           8       10        3
```

Comment: Yes, it does work, thanks a lot! Let's see if somebody posts something slightly simpler, otherwise I'll accept your answer

Comment: Heh, it's easily possible that there's something simple I'm missing.

Comment: This is simpler, but I had to reset the index.
`df_original = df2.copy()`

`df_original = df_original.reset_index()'

`df_original['ind_var'] = df_original['id'].map(ind_dict)`

`df_original['loc_var'] = df_original['rbd'].map(loc_dict)`

Comment: If you prefer the solution in my previous comment, please go ahead and edit your answer. Otherwise, I'll add it as an answer myself, I don't know what's considered cleaner in this site.

Comment: Just for completeness, there is no need to reset the index. We can access the different levels of the index this way:
`df2['ind_var'] = df2.index.map(lambda x : ind_dict[x[0]] )` and 
`df2['loc_var'] = df2.index.map(lambda x : loc_dict[x[1]] )`